# wxPython window won't close

Tags: python, wxpython

When you click on Cancel, it cancels... When you click OK, it pops the dialog back on. How can I fix this?

```
def quitApp(self, event):
    dial = wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Are you sure you want to quit?','Quit',  wxYES | wxNO)
    if dial.ShowModal() == wxID_YES:
        self.Close(true)
```

Comment: There's not near enough context code here to diagnose the issue.  Is `self` your App subclass, or your Frame, or what?

Comment: This is a method inside my "Frame" class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be that quitApp is called by the system CloseEvent handler? In that case, self.Close(true) only triggers a new CloseEvent, which in that case will call quitApp again and show a new dialog... and so on.

I suggest you quit the application with sys.exit(0) instead of self.Close(true).

Comment: This is a really strong possibility, and a great answer.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more (see my comment), I can take a few stabs:

1. If `self` is an App, then `self.ExitMainLoop()` will close the program.
2. If `self` is a Frame, then `self.Close(True)` is appropriate.
3. If `self` is anything else, then `sys.exit(0)` will shut down the Python Interpreter and close the program.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to provide more code. It looks like something else is triggering the `quitApp` function. Your function right there doesn't loop. It might be looping because it's trying to close and the event keeps getting called. Try using `self.Destroy()` instead to close the frame.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def CloseTheProgram( self, event ):
   dial = wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Are you sure you want to quit?','Quit',  wx.YES | wx.NO)
        if dial.ShowModal() == wx.ID_YES:       
            self.Close(True)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add an explanation.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.